# SQL Join 3 Different Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table below:

| StaffName | EffectiveDate | FieldType | FieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Terry | 1/1/1991 | Title | Instructor |
| Terry | 1/1/1991 | Department | LM |
| Terry | 1/1/1992 | Title | Senior Instructor |
| Owen | 1/1/1990 | Title | Administrator |
| Owen | 1/1/1990 | Department | LM |

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee.StaffName,  NameWithMaxDate.MaxDate
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN
(SELECT StaffName,
MAX(EffectiveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY StaffName) AS MaxDate
FROM Employee) AS NameWithMaxDate
ON Employee.StaffName = NameWithMaxDate.StaffName
```

I get the below result:

| StaffName | MaxDate |
| --- | --- |
| Owen | 1/1/1990 |
| Terry | 1/1/1992 |

I have another query:

```
SELECT StaffName,FieldValue
FROM Employee
WHERE FieldType = 'Department'
AND FieldValue = 'LM'
```

The result is below:

| StaffName | FieldValue |
| --- | --- |
| Terry | LM |
| Owen | LM |

I have one last query:

```
SELECT StaffName,FieldValue
FROM Employee
WHERE  FieldType = 'Title'
```

This is the result that I get:

| StaffName | FieldValue |
| --- | --- |
| Terry | Instructor |
| Terry | Senior Instructor |
| Owen | Administrator |

I am stuck on how to combine my 3 queries above to get the result which I desire as shown below:

| EffectiveDate | StaffName | Title | Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/1992 | Terry | Senior Instructor | LM |
| 1/1/1990 | Owen | Admin | LM |

Maybe my concepts of JOIN is not enough, or is there some other SQL functions that I have to use in this case?

Thank you

Comment: You're asking for (T-) SQL not about programming - better try: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Asking (T-)SQL based questions is completely on topic for [so] @riffnl . It's if you're asking more DBA based questions you need to ask on [dba.se]. For example, how to set up replication, index design, etc. Have a look at their [tour](//dba.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to get the last record per `StaffName` and `FieldType` by `Effective Date`.  We do this via the `WITH TIES` in concert with the window function `row_number()`

Then it becomes a small matter of a `conditional aggregation`

**Example  or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0e1adfd9d92d001a7cc9e992e6bf049d)**

```
Select EffectiveDate=max(EffectiveDate)
      ,StaffName
      ,Title      = max(case when FieldType='Title' then FieldValue end)
      ,Department = max(case when FieldType='Department' then FieldValue end)
 From  (
        Select top 1 with ties * 
         From  YourTable
         Order By row_number() over (partition by StaffName,FieldType Order by EffectiveDate desc)
      ) A
 Group By StaffName
```

**Results**

```
EffectiveDate   StaffName   Title               Department
1990-01-01      Owen        Administrator       LM
1992-01-01      Terry       Senior Instructor   LM
```